# Copying content (including constraints) of a Storyboard item to a xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a ViewController laid out in my Main.storyboard file. I want to copy everything from this ViewController layout into its own .xib file. Is there an easy I can I do this?

I have tried simply selecting everything and pasting but Xcode doesn't allow this. There has to be an easier way rather than laying it all out again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Press and hold command
2. Select all the items you want to copy
3. Press Command + C
4. Then select the xib you want to paste them in and press Command + V

This will copy all the items over.  They will retain their personal constraints.  But they won't retain any of their constraints that had to do with the view.  They will retain the constraints they have between each other.